# R ggplot2 add text in axis region

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I was able to add a text but the "2018" should be displayed inside X axis (that is, aligned with the other years, but still in 90 degrees). Any idea on how to do it without having to re-do the axis? I'd rather not touch how it was created, but open if it's necessary.

Current code to add 2018 dotted line and text:

```
MyPlot <- MyPlot + geom_vline(xintercept=YearForPlot, color="black", linetype="dotted")
MyPlot <- MyPlot + geom_text(aes(x=YearForPlot, y=0, angle=90, label=YearForPlot), color="black", size=8)
```

Image:
[image]

Small additional question: how to give a little more spacing between the "Year" axis label and the years ("2000")?

Thank you!

Comment: For the spacing, I'd use `vjust` for a minor change: `+ theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0))`. For a more drastic change, make the margin bigger: `theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(15, 0, 0, 0), units = "pt")))`

Comment: Or use `xlab("\nYear")`

Comment: Maybe `annotation_custom` for the year label outside the plotting area.